# Problem with PayPal smart buttons flow for subscriptions

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-buttons

I'm implementing PayPal smart buttons. The standard checkout button that uses `createOrder` works fine, but when I try to implement a [Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#subscriptions-with-smart-payment-buttons) button using `createSubscription`, it fails.

This is my current Sandbox code:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AREhuhCo83cfIjLVVtplS8UWtCBgvexoKJUpRz3zPwuN7Kf5BGczHeR3uozF&vault=true&intent=capture"></script>
<div id="pay"></div>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': 'P-17X768243C042641WL3VI5BY'
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            console.log('Transaction completed');
            console.log(details);
        });
    },
    onCancel: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    onError: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}).render('#pay');
</script>
```

This is the error I'm getting in response:

```
{
    "ack": "error",
    "message": "Unhandled api error",
    "meta": {
        "calc": "57517f6b99497",
        "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAcoHt23K4aX7rB2KTFdlMGLdO9t5%2BqNuHiXuuc82wAxBkVzSR%2Fh6yHLY_172c4fe7789"
    },
    "server": "YevVIjEkMPMB5pxeJvg1v5wTuIUCKnd7MkhOH71paANxpvJvd1vpHU2T4gEx4bTztqa8pw_Sni2pXQ7WBz4acfuFvBY3bxE7MhyIv9RIAPxl4Pu_xYLGaY7c1G5t8bj736tIHgJbXjITEBc_aJpzyhtg0O-PR5bSg9JUHpuv76hqQRr1pcnr1VEb2nAMYtGw6xLGyp6a8Of_8SiFMb63IYv7YMa4cQ7sKB54dbI1INigaxIGonrh_C7MXie1Td4pi7KcHePncFfuU6eIj83Ox0"
}
```

For those wondering, the `plan_id` **P-17X768243C042641WL3VI5BY** is valid. The product and plan were created successfully with a Sandbox app's token via curl. I've searched around, and there are some posts (in SO and other sites as well) with similar issues but with no solutions so far. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Create a new plan, perhaps a simple one to test, and try with that one